# How to insert 'n' number of rows on a sperate sheet based on 'n' being a number in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have to make my teams workload each month. It changes, based on number of working days how many auditors there will be available, and how may audits are needed for each company. If i can have the sheet auto balance the load based on how many total audits are needed for each company, then determine how many working days a person might have in the month that would be amazing.

But for now - I would really like to be able to have it create a separate sheet for each auditor with their name in column A and the name of the account in column B based on how many audits they have been assigned.

[image: example worksheet]

Comment: Record a macro doing what you want see the code understand and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to modify this a little for your needs...

```
workbook.sheet("yoursheet").rows(startRow & ":" & startRow+numberOfRowsYouWant).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

If you want to insert 5 lines at row 60, for example:

```
workbook.sheet("yoursheet").rows("60:" & 60+5).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.